Portfolio Gallery with Filtering - filter by unique URL
I am just wondering if anyone knows if you can apply a filter to a portfolio gallery page using  a unique URL (based upon using the 'Portfolio Gallery with Filtering' tutorial on w3schools).
Portfolio Gallery with Filtering Link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp
For example it might be something like this:
http://www.example.com/?filter=category
